# Single task issue with Spark ML pipeline

Tags: apache-spark

I have a spark ML pipeline with 4 stages. I pass a dataset (read from HDFS file), to each stage.In each stage in the transform method, I do a foreach on the dataset and call a REST service , the results are populated to the dataset and taken forward to the next stage. Finally outside the pipeline ,I persist the results to a database and also a file to HDFS.[image]

I submit the job to the yarn cluster (4 nodes). What I notice is that all the stages in the pipeline run in a single task essentially on a single node in the cluster. I have set 6 executors, 5 cores and 5gb RAM in the spark submit. I expected that the foreach will split the dataset across the nodes and run in parallel, but I see single node running all the calls.

Not sure if I need to do any re-partitioning or some other optimization to leverage the cluster. The file size in HDFS is about 600MB.

Comment: Did you try to try repartition() as you said?

Comment: No. I am not sure if I have to. Just reading to similar issues and got the hint.

Comment: Just try it, and see what will happen. It is absolutely one direction that you can try.

Comment: check the number of partitions that are created..use df.rdd.getNumPartitions method